# C#, ASP.NET MVC / MVC2: Add wildcard route for specific controller - help building route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

lets say I have a controller named Store. There is an index method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string val, long? id, int? id2)
{
  return View();
}
```

I want to fetch things like:

```
/my-store/some-text 
/my-store/some-text/
/my-store/some-text/123456789012335
/my-store/some-other-text/4562343462345
/my-store/some-other-bla-text/4562343462345/1
/my-store/some-other-bla-bla-text/45345723554/2
```

So the requerements are:
+ the controller link-text is "my-store" and has to route to Store controller
+ if there is only some text and id, then just leave id2 null
+ if there is only some text and no id, then just leave id and id2 null

Is the following correct?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Store", // Route name
    "my-store/{val}/{id}/{id2}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah looks good except you need to define a default value for {val} in your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Store", // Route name
"my-store/{val}/{id}/{id2}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", val = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Just remember to cleanse the string in val as if you have some funky characters then your link won't work.  Like let's say val equal *"thisis/val"*, then your link will be:

> /my-store/thisis/val/1212/12

Which would not hit your route and most likely return a 404